# adding client domain in SAN

Tags: openssl, ssl-certificate, certificate, client-certificates

Is it possible to put a domain that i dont own in the SAN of my certificate

client : client.com

me : domain.com

certificate SAN : "client.com, *.domain.com,"

it seems that if the client give me permission its possible. But i dont find revelant informations

i didn't try it but it seems like if everyone was doing that it could make everything crumble a little bit like impersonating, security wise i dont think its a good way of doing it but i'm interested of the possibility

Comment: This is not about programming or development and is offtopic, but: it depends on what you mean by 'my certificate'. To get a domain name in either Subject or SAN of a cert issued by a publicly-trusted CA like LetsEncrypt GoDaddy Sectigo etc you must prove 'control' of that domain, either honestly with the assistance of the true owner, or dishonestly by hijacking it (in which case if discovered or reported the cert will be revoked and thus not trusted). For a cert you create yourself e.g. with openssl as tagged you can put any name(s) you want, but that cert won't be trusted.

Comment: This is a strange request that smacks of an [XY problem](https://xyproblem.info/).